# Snoopy Failed to start snoopy.service: Unit snoopy.service not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, monitoring

i installed snoopy on  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and it got successfully installed but when i run > sudo systemctl start snoopy.service i get error- Failed to start snoopy.service: Unit snoopy.service not found

I tried sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade but still getting error. My main aim is to log all commands entered by user using scoopy. Also i can't find any scoopy.log in var/log/ directory.